# When I spot a question that ought to be in a different site, what do I do?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flags, migration

For example, I had posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80835/best-way-to-organise-ones-sh-bash-python-etc-scripts) on StackOverflow back when superuser wasn't still up.

I have flagged today the question as requiring mod intervention stating it ought to be moved to superuser, but I wonder:

1. whether this is the best way around it,
2. whether the mods who do get the notification are able to do something about it anyway, and
3. whether I should bother at all wrt this.

Help us help you, mods. How would you like to be bothered today? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alerting the mods is one solution.

Assuming you have less than the 3,000 rep needed to vote to close the other choice is to leave a comment. This will help confirm that someone else thinks the same as me (as a 3,000+ rep user) when I come to view the question. You have to be careful how you word your comment though as the OP might just ask the same question on the target site so when the original does get migrated it'll be a duplicate.

Whatever you do though, **don't** add a [belongs-on-*] tag to the question. While it'll get removed from the migrated question it sticks to the original and can't be removed. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30276/there-are-407-questions-tagged-belongs-on-serverfault-on-stack-overflow) for more discussion on this.

Comment: I can't add tags anyway :)

Comment: the OP "cross-posting" really isn't a reason not to migrate.  dupes can be cleared up/merged after the move.

Comment: @~quack - I wasn't suggesting that it was, just that you need to be careful what you put in the comment so the OP **doesn't** go off and repost the question straight away.

Comment: thx for the clarification, ChrisF.  your phrasing in the answer ("You have to be careful though...") is a bit amiguous as to what one needs to be careful about, and i misinterpreted.